# Could I change redis data structure list to set

Tags: list, redis, set

I used redis list structure to store data, but now I want to change the list type to set. Any command for this?

Answer (score 3):

No built-in way to do that. You need manually get items from the list and insert into the set. If your list is small, you can use the following lua script:

```
repeat
    local item = redis.call('lpop', KEYS[1])
    if (item) then redis.call('sadd', KEYS[2], item) end
until not item
```

However, if your list is very large, the script will block Redis for a long time. You have to incrementally move items from list to set:

1. call `LRANGE` to get some items (small batch) from list
2. call `SADD` to insert these items to set
3. call `LTRIM` to remove these items from list
4. go to step 1 until all items have been moved.